# Is there a way to indicate that a class has magic methods defined for every method on another class?

Tags: php, phpstorm, phpdoc

Is there a way to document that a certain class has magic methods for every method defined in another class?

I am using PhpStorm, so I would be happy with any solution that will get autocomplete to work properly for that.

```
class A
{
    // a bunch of functions go here...
}

/**
 * Class B
 * What should go here to make it work???
 */
class B
{
    private $aInstance;

public function __construct() {
    $this->aInstance = new A();
}

public function __call($name, $arguments) {
    // TODO: Implement __call() method.
    if(method_exists($this->aInstance, $name)) {
        return $this->aInstance->{$name}(...$arguments);
    }
    throw new BadMethodCallException();
}

    // a bunch more functions go here...
}
```

Comment: I think that `$this->aInstance->{$name}(...$arguments);` is deprecated in PHP 7.0 and later. Might need to use `call_user_func` there

Comment: Also, why can't `B` just extend `A`? Would easily resolve the problem

Comment: B already has a parent.

Comment: Hmm, have you tried something similar to this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15634021/how-to-document-magic-call-and-callstatic-methods-for-ides

Comment: The only way to do this via PHPDoc is to list every method manually via `@method` as stated in the previous comment (will work in other editors/IDEs that support it). In PhpStorm though the `@mixin className` will also work .. which might do the job for you here.

Comment: Putting in every method manually is not workable. Whenever any method signature in class A is updated, I'd need to go back and fix B.

Comment: The `@mixin` tag works.If you write an answer, I will accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The proper solution is to use supported `@method` PHPDoc tags. This way it will also work in other editors/IDEs that support PHPDoc and understand such standard tag.

This approach requires every method to be listed separately. More on this in another StackOverflow question/answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15634488/783119.

---

In current PhpStorm versions you may use not-in-PHPDoc-specs (and therefore possibly PhpStorm-specific) `@mixin` tag.

Adding `@mixing className` in PHPDoc comment for your target class should do the job for you.

```
/**
 * Class B
 * 
 * @mixin A
 */
class B
{
```

Basically, `@mixin` tag does what actual PHP's traits do.

**Please note** that there is no guarantee that support for such tag will not be removed at some point in the future, although it's pretty unlikely.