# PHPDoc: append methods to the current class, as if it were extending a class

Tags: cakephp, phpdoc

I'm using CakePHP 3 and PHPStorm 9 for my current PHP project and I have a class `GroupsTable` which is using the [`TreeBehavior`](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/behaviors/tree.html).

In my `GroupsController` I have the following docblock:

```
/**
 * Class GroupsController
 *
 * @property GroupsTable $Groups
 *
 * @package App\Controller
 */
```

With the `@property` part I make sure that I can access my `GroupsTable` methods via the autocompletion of PHPStorm by typing `$this->Groups->` and then it will show all the available methods of the `GroupsTable` class.

But, as I said before I added the `TreeBehavior` to this `GroupsTable`, and so I want to be able to see the methods of this behavior via the autocompletion as well. I access methods of the behavior via a call like this: `$this->Groups->recover()`, which is a method defined in the `TreeBehavior`. You could say CakePHP is "extending"  the behavior, but that's not what's fysically happening, resulting in a lack of autocompletion.

**So my question is:**

How can I *append* methods to a class, as if the current class is extending another class.

So in my case:

How can I add the `TreeBehavior` methods to the `GroupsTable`, so that PHPStorm "thinks" `recover()` is part of the `GroupsTable` class and therefore is able to autocomplete as such?

I tried things like `@property TreeBehavior $this` and `@var TreeBehavior $this` in the docblock of the `GroupsTable` class. I also tried other methods as defined in the PHPDoc manual but nothing seems to work.

*I find it hard to believe there is nothing to find about this subject via a search engine or on SO, but I can't seem to find anything about this. Perhaps because there is a term for it which I don't know?*

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40473017/is-there-a-way-to-indicate-that-a-class-has-magic-methods-defined-for-every-meth

Comment: @ndm the `@mixin` method seems to do the trick indeed. It's a shame it's not a PHPdoc supported tag though.