# PhpStorm how to remove "Method 'findById' not found in class ..." notice in Code Inspection?

Tags: phpstorm, cakephp-2.0, code-inspection

If I let the code inspection run through my CakePHP project code all magic methods like `findById()` or `findAllByName()` are marked as "undefined".

In the background they call the `__call()` method of the `Model.php` class.

**Is there an option that those are not marked as an error any more?** It is spamming my inspection output. Not a serious problem, but it would be nice to get rid of an error, which is not an error.

Comment: You can try `Downgrade severity if __magic methods are present in class` option for that inspection -- it will now be reported as "Weak Warning" instead of "Warning" so it much less noticeable (but still reported). The other way -- declare them via PHPDoc `@method` way so IDE is ware of them -- just look around on this site or internet in general -- there must be already made solutions/instructions for this.

Comment: E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/15634488/783119 or perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/a/40487530/783119 . Check other tickets tagged with same tags: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cakephp+phpstorm

Comment: I saw those, but regarded them as not helpful. Therefore my question.

Comment: have a look at https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-ide-helper

Comment: That really looks promising, but ist is "only" for cakePhp3, correct? Or does an version  for cakePhp2 exist, too?