# PhpStorm cannot find declaration to go with magic method

Tags: php, phpstorm

I want to go to the declaration of the method with <kbd>Ctrl + B</kbd>, but the model is return form a magic method. And there are some similar Model.

What can I do to go to the declaration?

The method has defined on the Order Model

[image]

The same as top

[image]

Here are Models

[image]

the magic method which returns the instance of $name Model

[image]

Comment: Declare your `m_order` and alike fields with `@property` tag (in PHPDoc comment for the appropriate class) so they provide correct typehint (what model they return) so that IDE may find the methods that model has.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, and kudo's for documenting your question! This is an excellent question. However this question has been asked before, and has some excellent answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15634021/how-to-document-magic-call-and-callstatic-methods-for-ides I'm voting to close this answer so stack overflow does noet get cluttered with duplicate questions.

Comment: @LazyOne Thanks, but it does not perfect, because there are  `m_order`,'m_student` or more model, it will take me much work to write `@property`, I want to a simpler way, like writing some thing on the `--get($name)`

Comment: @luohanqun Good luck with wishes. PhpStorm supports PHPDoc tags... and they do work _just fine_. I know no other way how it can be described in `__get()`. Maybe another IDE/editor can do .. but not PhpStorm.