# Laravel Routing: Where is the prefix() Method Defined?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, laravel-routing

In my example, I defined a route:

```
Route::prefix('home')->group(function(){
    Route::get('/test',....);
});
```

When I access `mydomain/home/test,` it works. However, I don't know where the `prefix` method is located. I think it might be in `Illuminate\Routing\Route.php.` But when I remove the `prefix` method on that, is it still working?

Comment: can u clear your route list cache?

Comment: yes, i just `php artisan route:cache` but the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@louisfischer answer is incorrect. The `Router::prefix` is not called at all.

The `prefix` method is called from `RouteRegistrar`, which is **finally forwarded to the `RouteRegistrar::attribute` method**.

You can verify this by looking in the `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route` docblock.

```
* @method static \Illuminate\Routing\RouteRegistrar prefix(string  $prefix)
```

Here is the complete flow:

1. The Route facade first forwards the call to `Illuminate\Routing\Router` through `Facade::__callStatic`.
2. Since `Router::prefix` is not a `public` method but a `protected` method, this call is forwarded to `RouteRegistrar::attribute` through the `Router::__call` method.
3. Finally the `prefix($url)` method is converted to `RouteRegistrar::attribute('prefix', $url)`

Comment: `\Illuminate\Routing\RouteRegistrar` is the return type. Check [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15634488/4559927) about the `@method` tag.

Comment: That's exactly my point. it is the return type because the `RouteRegistrar::attribute` returns `$this`. Whereas you're suggesting `Router::prefix` whose return type is string not RouteRegistrar. Your answer is wrong.

Comment: I guess you didn't even read the OP question. He asked where he can find the `prefix` method. My answer is correct and simple: in the `Illuminate\Routing\Router` class

Comment: No, he meant where he can find the `Route::prefix` method that is called. That refers to `RouteRegistrar::attribute`. The `Router::prefix` is not even called on `Route::prefix` and is totally irrelevant to the question.

Comment: "The `prefix` method is located in the class `Illuminate\Routing\Router`" answers pretty well the question "i don't know where is prefix method?" to me.

Comment: Yes because you didn't read the question. He was referring the `Route::prefix` method. The `Router::prefix` method is not the same as `Route::prefix`.

Comment: I think you are mixing things up. The `Route` facade references the `Illuminate\Routing\Router` class.

Comment: How does that relate to the question? You're the one who's mixing things up

Comment: Thankiu @louisfischer and Paras. This is what i looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

The `prefix` method may be used to prefix each route in the group with a given URI.

You can use this code:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'home'], function () {
   Route::get('test', 'yourController@yourFunctions');
}
```

or this

```
Route::prefix('home')->group(function () {
    Route::get('test', 'yourController@yourFunctions');
});
```

It doesn't matter because it gives same results.

More information: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#route-group-prefixes

Comment: Hi, I using Laravel 5.4, but i want to know where `prefix` method define?

Comment: I drilled down the `prefix` method and it was from `_ide_helper.php` it says like this: `@method static \Illuminate\Routing\RouteRegistrar prefix(string  $prefix)`

Comment: I cannot found `_ide_helper.php` file, and `prefix` method in `\Illuminate\Routing\RouteRegistrar`

Comment: The OP is not asking what code to use. He is asking where the `prefix` method is defined and why.

Answer (score 0):

The `prefix` method is located in the `Illuminate\Routing\Router` class.

The absolute path in a typical Laravel 5 application would be:

```
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php
```

**How to find it?**

You probably know that when you write `Route::` you are actually using the Laravel facade called `Route`. From there you can find the facade class reference in the official documentation of Laravel 5.4 at https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/facades#facade-class-reference. Here is the line you are looking for:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
|Facade |Class                     |Service Container Binding |
---------------------------------------------------------------
|Route  |Illuminate\Routing\Router |router                    |
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

**The flow**

1. The (protected) `prefix` method is handled by the `__call@Router`. `return (new RouteRegistrar($this))->attribute($method, $parameters[0]);` is executed
2. the `attribute@RouteRegistrar` method is called and the element `'prefix' => 'home'` is added to the `$this->attributes` array
3. Since the `attribute@RouteRegistrar` method returns `$this`, the `group@RouteRegistrar` method is called
4. The `group@RouteRegistrar` method calls the `group@Router` method
5. The `loadRoutes@Router` method is called. It will parse all routes present in the closure, i.e. `Route::get('/test', ...)`;
6. This time the `get` method is called on the class underlying the `Route` facade, the `Router` class. The `get@Router` method is executed
7. `addRoute@Router` is called, which in turn calls the `createRoute@Router` method
8. `createRoute@Router` calls `newRoute@Router` with the prefixed URI as second argument

You will notice that the `prefix@Router` method calls `getLastGroupPrefix@Router` which obviously retrieve the prefix of the last group.

Comment: But in `Illuminate\Routing\Router` prefix method return `string` ? but i think it must return `class`

Comment: I know you may think that it must return the class itself because of the method chaining. But this is made possible thanks to the [`Macroable` trait](https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Support/Traits/Macroable.html). Check [this concise article](https://unnikked.ga/understanding-the-laravel-macroable-trait-dab051f09172) as an introduction on the Laravel `Macroable` trait.

Comment: No that is incorrect. Macroable only works when we call `Route::macro`. In fact the prefix method in the `Router` class is not called on `Route::prefix`.

Comment: You just changed the meaning of your entire answer now that you've realized that my answer is the correct one and your original answer was incorrect. Wow! Great sportsmanship!

Comment: I never modified anything, just added things to be clearer. You can check the revisions ;)

Comment: Originally you said `Router::prefix` is called. Now you're saying `RouteRegistrar::attribute` is called. In fact you even argued that Router::prefix is called because of `Macroable`. Yes, your edits and comments are public for everyone to see.

Comment: I indeed **answered his question in the comments** too quickly. After your comment, I had a better look and added details to my answer.