# PhpDoc: @param with @method

Tags: php, phpdoc

Thereis a class. Most of methods are simple and can be processed with `__call()` method. So, then I can specify my methods with PhpDoc `@method` definition:

```php
/**
 * @method type11 m1(type1 $p)
 * @method type22 m2(type2 $p)
 * @method type33 m3(type3 $p)
 */
```

But how can I specify (and is it actually possible) params definition? For normal methods I use the `@param` definition.

I don't want to create empty methods for only to specify their params definitions:

```php
/**
 * @param type1 $p Definition
 * @return type11
 */
public function m1(type1 $p){}

/**
 * @param type2 $p Definition
 * @return type22
 */
public function m2(type2 $p){}

/**
 * @param type3 $p Definition
 * @return type33
 */
public function m3(type3 $p){}
```

Is it way to define such methods with only PhpDoc definitions?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15634021/how-to-document-magic-call-and-callstatic-methods-for-ides

Comment: Didn't understand. I saw the `@method` definition, but not it's `@params`.